# pull to refresh in android

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-2.0-eclair

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to implement Android Pull-to-Refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583484/how-to-implement-android-pull-to-refresh)

I have implemented pull to refresh in my app which works fine in 2.2, but in 2.0 it doesn't.

I couldn't find the method 'smoothScrollBy()' in 2.0.

Can anyone please give me the solution for this issue or any other alternative? How can I acheive pull to refresh functionality like in iphone?

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`smoothScrollBy` was introduced in API version 8, so it is not available in other versions.  (You can see what API version a method is available in on the far right hand side of the detailed API, like [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#smoothScrollBy%28int,%20int%29)).

I'm not sure what refreshing your app has to do with `smoothScrollBy` though.  If you have a `ListView` with an adapter, you can just update the contents of the adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: He's talking about using a special list header item at the top that triggers a content refresh when it becomes fully visible. In such a scheme usually you would want to smoothly scroll the list back to real content to reset after the refresh has been triggered or after a fling ends. The official Twitter app does this.

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged cannot be used in this case. As adamp said, he needs refresh list on the pull like twitter app. You answered wrong.

Answer (score 5):

You could also take a look to Johan Nilsson's android-pulltorefresh library:

https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh

It provides an out-of-the-box "pull to refresh" widget that replace the basic Android ListView.

Answer (score 1):

I've also implemented a robust, open source, easy to use and highly customizable PullToRefresh library for Android. You can replace your ListView with the PullToRefreshListView as described in the documentation on the project page.

https://github.com/erikwt/PullToRefresh-ListView

Comment: If you have another widget on top of the listview with pulltorefresh, on refreshing the listview header goes on top of the widget above.