# Overscroll (PullToRefresh) for 2.2 compatibility?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-2.2-froyo

OverScrolling was introduced in listviews in android 2.3. Is there a 3rd party library that provides a custom overscrolling implementation that is compat on froyo?

Comment: from another thread [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583484/how-to-implement-android-pull-to-refresh)

Comment: If I refer to another thread of stackoverflow as answer...it says "Trivial answer converted to comment" and it will convert my answer into a comment.

Comment: let's close as duplicate

Comment: @hunterp...I answered your question...now you can close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one open source project available on gitHub here is the [link](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh). And here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583484/how-to-implement-android-pull-to-refresh) for similar thread. Hope this help!!!