# Android: Pull to Refresh for GridView

Tags: android, gridview, pull-to-refresh

I'm currently looking for a possibility to implement a pull to refresh GridView.

Does anybody have a clue if there's a complete custom view like the one in [How to implement android pull to refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583484/how-to-implement-android-pull-to-refresh)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Chris Banes released a [library](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/) recently based on Johan Nilsson's [library](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh) that implements a `PullToRefreshGridView` widget. I have tried it and it perfectly works!

Comment: Hm, on my Wildfire (Android 2.1) the divider lines in the listview are kept blank sometimes. But the gridview works as expected! Thank you very much.