# Android pull-to-refresh or not design patterns

Tags: android, design-patterns, pull-to-refresh

Hi just wondering whether or not to add a pull to refresh in my app. I am used to ios so i know the pull to refresh feature well and i like it however i am unsure whether or not this is a standard in android.

Should i use pull to refresh or stick with a standard refresh button

Comment: as I found some (but very few) devices not have over scrolling that's why it is not very much genral in android..........

Comment: Both the iconic facebook and twitter apps have it. Whether or not it's a "standard", people have seen it and will not be surprised by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "recommended" use case for refresh on Android is a button in the Action Bar. That said, as Paul-Jan mentioned, the Facebook and Twitter apps both use it, and I think it's actually a very nice and intuitive UI pattern. I would maybe suggest going with both -- a refresh button in the Action Bar as well as pull to refresh.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the samples to pull to refresh here in these two links

[Link1](https://github.com/timahoney/Android-Pull-To-Refresh)

[Link2](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh)

and here is the Stack overflow discussion

[SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583484/how-to-implement-android-pull-to-refresh)