# Android - Pull-down Refresh Feature on LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, pull-to-refresh

I wanted to ask can I implement pull-down refresh option on a linear layout control, I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583484/how-to-implement-android-pull-to-refresh) & other examples also but they all are for "ListView" control.

Comment: Have a look at [Chris Banes' pull-to-refresh implementation](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/tree/master/library/src/com/handmark/pulltorefresh/library), which is available for several views, including `ListView`, `GridView`, `ScrollView` and `WebView`. You might be able to simple use the `ScrollView` version and wrap that around your `LinearLayout`. Alternatively it should be relatively easy to implement your own using the building blocks in that library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MH

Have a look at Chris Banes' pull-to-refresh implementation, which is available for several views, including ListView, GridView, ScrollView and WebView. You might be able to simple use the ScrollView version and wrap that around your LinearLayout. Alternatively it should be relatively easy to implement your own using the building blocks in that library.

This Worked for me.