# android listview pull down to create new row

Tags: android, listview

I doing something like this: when user at the top of listview, they can pull down to create new row, new row will come from top and outside of view port. Is it possible to extends ListView or I need to create a whole custom list view with AdapterView

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement Android Pull-to-Refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583484/how-to-implement-android-pull-to-refresh)

Comment: Nope, pull to create new row from the top, not refresh the list

Comment: How are they different? You pull to create a new row is the equivalent to the pull to refresh concept. If I am wrong, please do clarify on what you mean by _create a new row_ but not/without refreshing the `ListView`?

Comment: Do you know Clear app on ios? something like that, pull a new row, coming from the top of the list

Comment: @complez these does the same what you are asking... don't confuse with the "refresh" word.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look into Pull to refresh list view

Follwoing are refrences

1. [PullToRefresh-ListView](https://github.com/erikwt/PullToRefresh-ListView)
2. [Android-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh)