# Pull to refresh like gmail new (4.5) application

Tags: android, gmail, android-actionbar, pull-to-refresh

In the new gmail application (4.5) the refresh is done by "Pull-to-Refresh" action in the Actionbar:

[image]

[image]

Where can I find more information about that "Pull-to-Refresh"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583484/how-to-implement-android-pull-to-refresh

Comment: This link regarding the old way to do that... (2 years post). It's look like gmail does it in a new way.

Comment: Rather than a real "pull to refresh" it appears to be a simple gesture detector that is detecting a downward swipe.

Comment: For someone with the same question: http://www.tutecentral.com/android-pull-to-refresh/

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Chris Banes (the same guy that implemented the best pull to refresh component for android) also implemented the GMail like Pull To Refresh.

You can find it here: https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh

Note that this project is still under development so the current API may change.

**Update:**

Both `ActionBar-PullToRefresh` and `Android-PullToRefresh` are deprecated. Standart way to implement a pull to refresh is using `SwipeRefreshLayout` of v4 support library.

Here is the required steps:

- Create a root or sub layout with SwipeRefreshLayout and put a scrollable item in it.

  ```
  <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
      ...>

  <ListView
      .... />

  </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
  ```
- Add a refresh listener

  ```
  SwipeRefreshLayout srl = ...;
  srl.setOnRefreshListener(
      new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
          @Override
          public void onRefresh() {
              ...
          }
      });
  ```

You can find a nice tutorial about it below:

[SwipeRefreshLayout: How to use](http://antonioleiva.com/swiperefreshlayout/)

Comment: This project is no longer maintained, be aware.

Comment: https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh looks still maintained (last commit sept 24). Did you mean Android-PullToRefresh? Because his docs do say that old project is no longer maintained.

Comment: Also, this tutorial on ActionBar-PullToRefresh might be helpful: http://www.tutecentral.com/android-pull-to-refresh/

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html

Comment: Thank you Chiara! Funny how googling "Android pull to refresh" doesn't show that page