# Android ListView Pull Down to Refresh

Tags: android, listview

Is there any default function that exists like in iOS to update a listview ? Or any other library ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pull to refresh like gmail new (4.5) application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975544/pull-to-refresh-like-gmail-new-4-5-application)

Comment: [Thank you, Google!](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh) (time 0,850ms)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@elimirks pointed me to correct direction for using [ActionBar-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh), but for being newbie I was getting a lot or errors and was not able to use it well until I found [ActionBar Pull To Refresh Tutorial](http://www.tutecentral.com/android-pull-to-refresh/). To use `ActionBar-PullToRefresh` the other library [SmoothProgressBar](https://github.com/castorflex/SmoothProgressBar) is also required and need to be configured.

Thanks.

Comment: This solution requires external third party libraries. If you take a look at my answer, it shows you how to use the android component, supported by google, and in my opinion easier and faster to use. Also, it is a new component that had only been added to the library last month or so.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to use the SwipeRefresh in next project. I tried to use it but could not make it work and was also not sure if it will work with older versions of android.

Answer (score 39):

This is now supported by the support library and called `swipeRefreshLayout`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html

And here is an example: http://antonioleiva.com/swiperefreshlayout/