# failed import library for pulltorefresh webview

Tags: java, android

i'm using this [this](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) for my webview.

May i know how to import to my eclipse i tried import android project from existing code but the library folder unable to import. Any guide for this?

Comment: where have u put ur library project on ur loacal machine??? I mean put it in workspace and then import

Comment: As its project make it as library and use it. or compile the project generate the .jar to import it in ur project.

Comment: check this [link][1] Pull To Refresh for Android


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583484/how-to-implement-android-pull-to-refresh

Answer (score 0):

please try using import project option and check this guide http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#wiki-ReferencingLibraryProject