# Android Lollipop - Pull to refresh

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, pull-to-refresh

I am trying to implement pull-to-refresh in Android. I know there is `SwipeRefreshLayout` but with all the newly designed Google apps like Drive (see attached) for Lollipop, I have noticed there is a new refresh  icon that comes in the view when pulled. I tried looking it online but in vain. 
Has Android released this as a part of the Material Design? Any ideas about how to implement it?

EDIT: Some people have pointed out how this is a duplicate of [How to implement a Pull-to-refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583484/how-to-implement-android-pull-to-refresh). It is not the same question. You'll see it if you read the question properly.

[image]

Comment: it is released. SwipeRefreshLayout has this fancy button out of the box

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement Android Pull-to-Refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583484/how-to-implement-android-pull-to-refresh)

Comment: @MarianPaździoch if you look closely, its not.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This is `SwipeRefreshLayout` . Version 21 of the support library includes it replacing the old style.

Answer (score 19):

1. Download the latest Lollipop SDK and Extras/Android support library
2. Set Project's Build Target to Android 5.0 (otherwise support package can have errors with resources)
3. Update your libs/android-support-v4.jar to 21st version
4. Use android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout plus android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener

Detailed guide could be found here: http://antonioleiva.com/swiperefreshlayout/

Plus for ListView I recommend to read about canChildScrollUp() in the comments ;)

Answer (score 7):

I like this guide the best and its really easy to understand: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/implementing-swipe-to-refresh/

1. Add the following to gradle:

   `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'`
2. Add the swipe to refresh to your layout - put in listview or recyclerview in the middle of the swiperefreshlayout:

   ```
       <ListView
           android:id="@+id/activity_main_listview"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           >
       </ListView>

   </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
   ```
3. Add in your code for the mainactivity:

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   ListView mListView;
   SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
   Adapter mAdapter;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.acivity_main);
     SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout);
     mListView = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_list_view);
     mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(){
     String[] fakeTweets = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fake_tweets);
     mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fakeTweets)
     listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
   });
   }
   ```

   }
4. Don't forget to call mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false); once your refreshing ends.

Comment: Add some code form that link to avoid error if in future link is not reachable

Answer (score 4):

hi If you wan't to develop such a kind of Layout then please follow this url, i was used it it's an awesome.

https://github.com/stormzhang/SwipeRefreshLayoutDemo

Comment: Link is broken. It is usually not a good idea to only provide links to solve an issue.

Answer (score 3):

And the literal icon is in here:

> http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/v_1/quantumexternal/0B08MbvYZK1iNZ19ldS1aNzdTQkU/material-design-icons-1.0.0.zip

[source](http://www.google.com/design/spec/resources/sticker-sheets-icons.html#sticker-sheets-icons-components)