# What Pull to Refresh view is this?

Tags: java, android

I am wanting to implement Pull To Refresh in my application, but I was wanting to find something else other than using the Actionbar Pull to Refresh Design. I found a couple of apps (Umano / Reddit is Fun) that implement this circular overlay Pull to refresh style and I was wondering if anyone knows what library they are using? I just assumed it was a library because they are basically the same in terms of animation and flow. Its a circle that overlays the listview. Anyone know by chance?

Some screenshots for reference:

[image: Umano]

[image: Reddit is Fun]

Comment: Try **`uiautomatorviewer`** and see what it tells you about that view. I have not tried it with a custom `View`, and so it's possible that it will not give you the fully-qualified class name for it, but it might.

Answer (score 1):

This is the `SwipeRefreshLayout`, someone asked a very similar question here here: [Android Lollipop - Pull to refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26807763/android-lollipop-pull-to-refresh)

That should solve your problem