# Android ListView Pull Down and Pull Up

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, pull-to-refresh

I am new on Android Applications development. I want to know how to implement **Pull down refresh and Pull up get more item from server in Listview**.
How can I do it? 
My Code get items from server is below.

```
private class DownloadJSONItems extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressbar
        if (!prefs) {

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        // Create an array
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
        jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("Server URL",latitude, longitude);
        try {

            // Locate the array name in JSON
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("places");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                double convertString = Double.parseDouble(jsonobject.getString("distance"));
                double convertKMToMile = convertString * 0.6124;
                String convertedValue = String.format("%.2f",convertKMToMile);
                // Retrive JSON Objects
                map.put("places_name", jsonobject.getString("places_name"));
                map.put("distance", convertedValue);
                map.put("places_icon", jsonobject.getString("places_icon"));
                // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                arraylist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(jsonarray.length()), 6000).show();
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), arraylist);
        // Set the adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Close the progressbar
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (prefs) {

            prefs = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Use this library to get your work done.
https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh

Comment: You can use. https://github.com/erikwt/PullToRefresh-ListView , https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583484/how-to-implement-android-pull-to-refresh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a nice library for that https://github.com/Maxwin-z/XListView-Android

For Refresh:

```
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            start = ++refreshCnt;
            items.clear();
            geneItems();
            // mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(XListViewActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, items);
            mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            onLoad();
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

For load more:

```
@Override
public void onLoadMore() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            geneItems();
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            onLoad();
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried alot of libraries and this one works like a charm, Thank you!