# ListView with specific behaviour

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a `ListView`, and I have to implement specific behaviour for it.

When user scrolls up the `ListView` , which is in initial position:

1. `ListView` should move down a bit;
2. `ProgressBar` should appear;

Next image shows the result that I want to achieve:

[image]

Any suggestions how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SwipeRefreshLayout` from support-v4 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html

Wrap the ListView in a SwipeRefreshLayout in xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

And set the listener in your `onCreate()`:

```
SwipeRefreshLayout swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe);
swipe.setOnRefreshListener(this);
```

and implement it

```
@Override 
public void onRefresh() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            swipe.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: @hornet2319 no problem

Answer (score 1):

"There's a [library](https://github.com/Maxwin-z/XListView-Android) for that"

[another library](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh)

I believe this library does what you're looking for.

[image]

I got this picture from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27143485/android-listview-pull-down-and-pull-up)

There are lots of libraries doing similar things like in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOYtPF-4RPg

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SwipeRefreshLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html) or other library as suggested in @Cobbles answer.

It is not exactly the view you looking for, but the same feature. The advantage of swipe refresh layout is that is part of android support library and user are used to see it.