# How to make refresh animation with android listview?

Tags: android, listview, animation

I have a listview for my android app and I want to make an animation at the top of the list view when the user over scrolls like one the one for the instagram or twitter app. How would I go about this. Is there a method that is called when the user over scrolls and I was thinking about using a frameanimation for the actually animation.

Comment: Sorry I just found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583484/how-to-implement-android-pull-to-refresh

Answer (score 2):

You can add a swipe refresh layout on your xml file:

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/favs_refresher"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/favs_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Then on your activity:

```
    swipeRefresher = (SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.favs_refresher);
    swipeRefresher.setOnRefreshListener(this);
```

Be sure that your activity implements `SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener`

then you can make use of the `onRefresh()` method:

```
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    //do something
}
```